# How get all files and folders name into a directory of a client?

Tags: javascript

So I need get the all files of a directory of my client in JS.
I make a file manager and I need to import a directory. So for this, I think I need to get all files and folder name of the directory of my client and the content of her files and folder to build a zip file and import this zip file with AJAX to my PHP.

Comment: Not sure of your question - are the files on the client PC or the server?  JS can't access the local filesystem so hopefully the server.  You can use PHP scandir() or glob() to build a JSON object of the contents and echo that back to the JS.  Have you tried anything yet?  If so edit your post to include attempts.

Comment: So, the client can use a zip program to zip her folder in a single zip file, then you just provide a way of uploading the file. There are many, many examples of how to upload files on Stack Overflow and the internet at large...

Comment: you need make it in server app, client js cant acces to files